# Как добавить новые вычисляемые столбцы c условиями?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, анализ-данных, статистика

У меня есть датасет с векторами, разбитыми на три класса. Первый столбец означает принадлежность к классу и может принимать следующие значения: 1, 0, -1.

Моя задача, при помощи корреляции выявить в каждом из классов подклассы наиболее похожие друг на друга векторов.

Например на рисунке, который я привел ниже, вектор №60 относится к классу обозначенному '0'. И мы видим, что коэффициент корреляции говорит нам о том, что вектора №63 и №68, принадлежащие также этому классу '0' очень на него похожи. И вот эти три вектора 60, 63, 68 - новый подкласс векторов.
Я хочу получить эти наборы векторов и продолжить изучать их взаимосвязи.

[image: вот как я бы хотел получить в идеале]

Не могу понять, как можно сделать последние три столбца, не понимаю как сделать и сравнить выборки принимая во внимание соответствие к определенному классу.

Подскажите как можно их вычислить, чтобы получилось как на картинке у меня?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# загружаю файл с данными. 
# Первый столбец обозначает принадлежность к одному их трех классов обозначенных цифрами 1, 0, -1

fn = 'http://kramer.su/media/cms_page_media/downloads/dataset_corr200.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(fn, index_col=None, header=None, delimiter=';')

# Уменьшаю размер датафрейма для наглядности. Вообще полный файл состоит из нескольких тысяч строк
df = df.iloc[60:71, :]

# получаю таблицу корреляций по строкам, исключая первый столбец
dfcorr = df.iloc[:,1:].T.corr() 

# обнуляю диагональ
dfcorr.values[tuple([np.arange(len(dfcorr))]*2)] = 0


# добавляю в таблицу корреляций маркер, указывающий принадлежность вектора к одному из трех классов 
dfcorr["CLASS"] = df[0]

# найти максимальную корреляцию среди других классов
dfcorr["MAX"] = dfcorr.max() 

# найти минимальную корреляцию среди векторов этого же класса, если такие есть
# причем нужно выводит минимум, если он выше чем в столбце 'MAX'.
dfcorr["MIN"] = dfcorr.min()

# вывести все индексы векторов этого же класса, но с корреляцией выше чем в столбце 'MAX'  
dfcorr["list"] = str(['self', 1,2,3,4])

dfcorr
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можете объяснить суть того, что вы хотите сделать? Что значит выявить подклассы?

Comment: Я хочу найти группы векторов, у которых высокая корреляция. В каждом из классов есть случайные вектора, они как шум, а есть такие, которые повторяются с какой-то закономерностью и вот образцы таких векторов мне и нужно найти. 

Данный набор векторов описывает поведение посетителей на сайте.
1 - означает что это важный пользователь для сайта.
0 - безразличный пользователь. Он уйдет не сделав целевого действия.
-1 - эти вредители.

Comment: "Подклассами" я называю вектора, которые имеют в датасете несколько похожих копий с корреляцией >0.9 и такая высокая корреляция должна встречаться только у векторов одного класса. Если вдруг проверяемый вектор показал высокую корреляцию с вектором из другого класса, то это говорит о том, что этот вектор не несет в себе устойчивого сигнала.
Я смог объяснить свою задачу?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
In [59]: dfcorr['top_3_corr'] = dfcorr.apply(lambda c: c.nlargest(3).index.tolist())

In [60]: dfcorr
Out[60]:
          60        61        62        63        64        65        66        67        68        69        70    top_3_corr
60  0.000000  0.714060  0.703013  0.855609  0.784027  0.609506  0.783473  0.685364  0.798138  0.616653  0.651044  [63, 68, 64]
61  0.714060  0.000000  0.708653  0.728998  0.667181  0.745261  0.657862  0.750011  0.681522  0.703240  0.741851  [67, 65, 70]
62  0.703013  0.708653  0.000000  0.735077  0.677028  0.660202  0.853965  0.714482  0.662345  0.614973  0.646008  [66, 63, 67]
63  0.855609  0.728998  0.735077  0.000000  0.867109  0.620753  0.704216  0.684166  0.834251  0.671712  0.677671  [64, 60, 68]
64  0.784027  0.667181  0.677028  0.867109  0.000000  0.635168  0.666226  0.637260  0.884067  0.659621  0.647480  [68, 63, 60]
65  0.609506  0.745261  0.660202  0.620753  0.635168  0.000000  0.615755  0.880323  0.703466  0.742815  0.694952  [67, 61, 69]
66  0.783473  0.657862  0.853965  0.704216  0.666226  0.615755  0.000000  0.682558  0.744857  0.624437  0.714835  [62, 60, 68]
67  0.685364  0.750011  0.714482  0.684166  0.637260  0.880323  0.682558  0.000000  0.734051  0.708425  0.675987  [65, 61, 68]
68  0.798138  0.681522  0.662345  0.834251  0.884067  0.703466  0.744857  0.734051  0.000000  0.683177  0.679463  [64, 63, 60]
69  0.616653  0.703240  0.614973  0.671712  0.659621  0.742815  0.624437  0.708425  0.683177  0.000000  0.890475  [70, 65, 67]
70  0.651044  0.741851  0.646008  0.677671  0.647480  0.694952  0.714835  0.675987  0.679463  0.890475  0.000000  [69, 61, 66]
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь. Но это немного не то. В вашем случае выводятся статичное количество трех максимальных значений, но мне нужно вычислить максимум среди векторов других классов и получить все индексы ( не только 3) векторов из этого же класса со значениями выше максимума вычисленного на предыдущем шаге. Я сделал картинку показывающую наглядно три шага вычисления и прикрепил её к основному посту. Посмотрите, пожалуйста. Надеюсь так станет понятнее задача.

Comment: Может мне имеет смысл разбить задачу на три части для удобства?

Comment: @Mavar, да, пожалуй стоит разбить... Но самое главное - я не понимаю для чего отдельно выбирабтся коэффициенты корреляции для  разных классов

Comment: хорошо, разобью. Каждый вектор это пользователь на сайте, если он совершает целевое действие, его помечаем "1", если не совершает помечаем "0". И вот представим, что на сайт заходит новый пользователь и мы на основе корреляции сравниваем его с историей других пользователей. Если корреляция покажет что он одновременно относится сразу к двум классам, то в этом нет полезной информации.

Comment: Но если мы найдем такие образцы векторов из класса "1", которые хорошо коррелируют между собой и при этом плохо коррелируют с векторами из класса "0" - мы можем считать что нашли устойчивый набор векторов с которыми и будем сравнивать новых пользователей на сайте